# what are the custom parameters in RMI indicator?

Tags: mql4

Hey I've been trying to add this custom made indicator into my code but the problem is I can't find the indicator's parameters.

Here's what I've been trying to do:

```
void OnTick()
{
int RMI_Value1  = iCustom(NULL,0,"RMI",14,5);
Print(RMI_Value1);
}
```

Yet the output is always 0.

This link below is the source code of RMI.
https://pastebin.com/dJjvDZ7y

Comment: Please try to make your post self-contained, i.e. make a minimal working example that reproduces your error, as further explained in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The indicators binds external parameters using [`SetIndexBuffer()`](https://docs.mql4.com/customind/setindexbuffer), so it's going to be:

```
SetIndexBuffer(0,RMIBuffer);
SetIndexBuffer(1,PosBuffer);
SetIndexBuffer(2,NegBuffer);
```

The number of parameters is specified by [`IndicatorBuffers()`](https://docs.mql4.com/customind/indicatorbuffers). And its label is set by [`SetIndexLabel()`](https://docs.mql4.com/customind/setindexlabel).